# WAMP - Multiple WordPress/Joomla! Projects

Tags: wordpress, joomla, wampserver

This question may be redundant but I am unable to get anything working from what I've read.

I have a fresh installation of the latest WAMP server on my Windows 64 bit machine residing within the c:/ folder.

I have successfully downloaded and installed WordPress and Joomla!, however bringing over existing projects seems to fail.

I was given the task to work on an existing Wordpress and Joomla! site. I created folders for them within c:/wamp/www like the other two defaults. I also created the correct database in the phpMyAdmin however when I navigate directly to is via browser is the issue.

### Default Wordpress URL

"http://localhost/wordpress/" [works just fine]

### Downloaded Wordpress URL

"http://localhost/bridges/" which relocates me to "http://localhost:8010/bridges/" and throws a "Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to localhost:8010"

Any idea of why this is happening would be greatly appreciated. I will supply more info if need be. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm this sounds odd. I have never had a problem with multiple Joomla sites on wamp and you definitely shouldn't be getting redirected upon page view. I assume you have 2 separate databases for each site and they both connect to them correctly.

Comment: Yes, I created two different DBs using the same admin of "root" and the same host of "localhost". I modified nothing else as these were both fresh installs.

Comment: Could it have something to do with the downloaded WordPRess folder not being installed? I don't see where the port 8010 comes in as i haven't set that anywhere.

Comment: when you installed Joomla and wordpress, did you set the "host" to "localhost" ?

Comment: I only installed the default wordpress and joomla! sites and yes i set the host to localhost. The other two folders I didn't install. I just put them in the same directory c:/wamp/www/ Do they need to be installed like the default ones to work properly?

Comment: what are the 2 other folders for?

Comment: The other wordpress folder has an existing wordpress project in it already with all the modifications. The other joomla! folder is from a client that wants me to work on his existing site that i'm trying to set up locally properly.

Comment: ah ok, well unless you need to use them to work on, you don't need to install/set them up. the port 8010 is obviously coming from somewhere so double check the global configuration in the Joomla backend and same for the Wordpress dashboard. There must be a reference to it somewhere. Not sure how this could happen if you didn't add it, I had no problem with multiple Joomla and Wordpress sites in the localhost directory

Comment: The port 8010 was there before i pulled anything Joomla! related. It happened with the custom wordpress project. I searched the entire folder for that port and nothing returned. Maybe I can check the wordpress config and see if something in there was configured with it but I figure it would have come up in the source somewhere. I'm trying to set them up on my mac currently while at work.

Comment: Maybe trying installing a fresh copy of WAMP and setup the Joomla project first, and the Wordpress one after.

Comment: I got the custom joomla folder working locally. I fear the custom wordpress one might be the culprit in this scenario. Thanks for everything though.

Comment: well it's wordpress, I rest my case :P hope you get it sorted and please share the solution if you figure it out. Would actually like to know the cause of this. Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was ridiculous. The settings were set to localhost:8010 so I had to modify them via phpMyAdmin or if you can get to the wp-admin then modify them there.